# How to take mongodump for 1 collection from my Database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to take mongodump for 1 collection from my Database

```
../mongodump --db db_name --collection collection_name --out /home/dell/999/
```

i got this error

```
bash: ../mongodump: No such file or directory
```

This is working for entire db backup

```
./mongodump --out /home/dell/777/ --db dbname
```

But back up for single collection from a database not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) to export collection  data:

```
mongoexport --db test --collection mycollection --out myCollection.json
```

Comment: Where it is stored i want to store this location /home/dell/999/

Comment: use path to store /home/dell/999/myCollection.json

Comment: showing error bash: ../mongoexport: No such file or directory

Comment: ensure  folder structure  is exists and read write executable permission available for that directory

Comment: no its not working

bash: ../mongoexport: No such file or directory

I am using db.version() --  3.0.12

../mongoexport --db employee --collection user --out /home/mathan/299/user.json

Answer (score 0):

If it's a replica set and you want to use the `--uri` you should use it like this cause documentation states that you can't specify some options when using `--uri`

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb://user:password@mongo-en-1.example.io:27017,mongo-en-2.example.io:27017,mongo-en-3.example.io:27017/$Databasename?replicaSet=$replicasetname&authSource=admin"  --collection $collectionname
```